# Filename is returned as null when an outlook item (.msg file) is added as attachment to an outlook email sent

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm getting null as the return value for the method `getFileName()` (which is used to get the filename associated with the body part) when I send an email from Outlook with Outlook item (.msg file as an attachment). I also tried using the `getName()` of `DataHandler()` but still getting the value as null.

How to handle this scenario of having outlook item (.msg file) as an attachment?

**PS**: I was able to retrieve the file name for every other attachment (.png, .doc, .pdf etc.), I'm facing trouble only with .msg attachment.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi and welcome: please add code to your question showing us what you have done so fare. Look here for more info -->  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

What you observe is valid for message sent from Outlook. Let's see the source of the message sent from Outlook when it contain regular attachment. For example the header of the attachment would look like ...

```
Content-Type: image/png; name="404.png"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="404.png"; size=30193; creation-date="Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:44:01 GMT"; modification-date="Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:44:01 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

The `filename` field is completed for attached image and when you would try to retrieve it it would return `404.png`.

Now let's look at the source of the message with attached `.msg` attachment inside. This for example would loooks like ...

```
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Disposition: attachment; creation-date="Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:40:28 GMT"; modification-date="Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:40:28 GMT"
```

As you see there is no `filename` specified for this type of attachment and when you would try to retrieve it it would return `null`.

The suggestion is very obvious ... When you handling attachment take a look on `Content-Type` and if this is embedded message which doesn't have the name, just set whatever you like. For example Gmail would display "noname" in attachments list.

Comment: To be clear, there's no requirement that any attachment of any type ever have a file name, so your code always has to handle the case that a file name was not supplied.  And of course be careful with how much you "trust" a file name that was supplied.